# Engine oil refill volume in Bajaj Pulsar 220

Tags: motorcycle, oil-change, bajaj

My bike's user manual recommends using 1150ml of "Bajaj 10000" 20W40 1.2 litre engine oil.

Needless to say it results in pathetic performance.

So I am thinking of switching to Motul 5100 15W40 ; and this comes in a 1 litre pack.

So my questions are :

**Is this 150ml going to make any difference?**

**15W and 20W oils don't alter the performance, do they?**

Temperatures in my place rarely go below 19 degrees celsius

Comment: The important thing to do when changing oil is to refill the oil to the proper level by checking the marks on the dipstick or the engine case.  Your motorcycle might hold 1150ml, but that doesn't mean it's all going to drain out when you do an oil change.  Always fill by checking, in a car or a motorcycle or whatever.  Don't rely only on specs.

Answer (score 8):

**I run the manufacturer spec oil**

Why? Because they designed the engine, I didn't.

The performance increase with a thinner oil is negligible. The oil level is associated with the height of the oil pickup in the crankcase so unless you are ok with possibly encountering a situation where your oil pump sucks air once in awhile I would stay with the appropriate quantity of oil no matter what.

[How to understand different engine oils?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/how-to-understand-different-engine-oils?rq=1)

**You want performance?**

If you are looking for performance increases that are meaningful I would consider the following.

- Jet Kit
- Free Flow Air Filter
- Free Flow Exhaust
- Piggy Back ECU

Beyond that you are looking at engine work.

Here are some links that might be beneficial for you.

- [Carburettor jetting on installation of aftermarket air filter](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16727/carburettor-jetting-on-installation-of-aftermarket-air-filter/16728#16728)
- [Do I need to reprogram ECU when adding custom Air filter](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17531/do-i-need-to-reprogram-ecu-when-adding-custom-air-filter)
- [Is it possible to fit mashroomhead air filter in Honda Stunner CBF 125?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27100/is-it-possible-to-fit-mashroomhead-air-filter-in-honda-stunner-cbf-125/27101#27101)
- [What are the pros and cons of installing a high-performance air filter on a bike?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-installing-an-filter-on-a-bike/26326#26326)
- [straight pipes and carb rejetting?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6131/straight-pipes-and-carb-rejetting/25577#25577)
- [Symptoms of Lean or Rich carb settings on a motorcycle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/732/symptoms-of-lean-or-rich-carb-settings-on-a-motorcycle/23937#23937)

Not all of those links apply to your motorcycle but it should help you with gaining some foundation information on where you might want to go regarding gaining additional performance and some of the challenges you may encounter on your path to MOAR Horsepower.

Comment: Any comments regarding the difference of 150ml ?

Comment: @swarm  I edited the response to include my view on quantity of oil.  I would leave it.  It's not worth the savings. IMO.

Comment: @swarm  Thanks for the edits.  Very much appreciated by everyone!  good lookin out.  Cheers.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of Bajaj Pulsars. In my experience i would suggest not to use company specified engine oil. You can switch to motul similar spec fully synthetic engine oil which is way too expensive than Bajaj oils. Buy 2 Oil packs and fill 1.150 Ltr and save the rest for refills. Check oil level once every 1000 Kms and refill as needed.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not a problem. Of course you can change the engine oil.
But Shell oil is much better than Motul and Castrol. For better performance use this grade oil 20w50 grade oil .

Comment: The grade 20w50 does not simply improve performance. It's a technical specification for oil to used in particular atmospheric conditions.